# Windows service is not working as expected - C#

Tags: c#, .net, service, windows-services, file-watcher

I've built a windows service using `FileWatcher` class. It has to detect the incoming files in a folder and move them to the new location.

My code is running fine as console application but not working as Windows service.The files are staying in the Source folder only. They are not moving to the destination.I've given full access to the folders and service running in LOCAL SYSTEM account. Can you please point out the error. Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsService1
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            bulk_watch();
        }

        public static void bulk_watch()
        {
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = @"C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\FW_Source";            
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;     
            watcher.Filter = "*.*";                              
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged); 
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        }

        public static void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {


            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Downloads\FW_Source");
            FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.*");
            foreach (var f in files)
            {

               File.Move(f.FullName, System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\FW_Dest", Path.GetFileName(f.FullName)));

            }

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Have you tried to debug the windows service? Please provide more details about what is not ok.

Comment: Insufficient rights for access  C:\Users\ADMIN maybe?

Comment: The flies are not moving to the destination. The file is staying as it is in source folder

Comment: @duDE. I 've given full access to the folder. The code is working fine as console appl. But not as windows service.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Services run under the LocalSystem account by default (unless you specify another account when you install them). You will need to grant this account access to both folders.

Comment: Hi. I was running windows service under Local System and full access was given to the folders too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to create the service with username and password:

```
sc create "ServiceName" binPath= "G:\services\service.exe" DisplayName= "ServiceName" start= "auto" obj= "username"   password= "password"
```

Repace :
ServiceName, exe file location, DisplayName, username and password.

Comment: Hi.Thanks for your comment. Is there a way the above program to run without UserID and Password..?

Comment: The service requires enough permission to access files which it is not getting in this scenario because the folder location is with the Admin user's private folder location. You can either move file location to a generic drive(other than your C drive) or use the admin username and password.

Comment: When you are running it as a console app it is using your username to access the file, hence it is working at that time.